# Detect if light is on or not based on color detection on poor lightning conditions

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect if traffic light is on based on color detection. The problem is that, because of how sun light impacts on it, appears to be on when it's off. Currently i'm applying standard color detection using opencv in python with hsv color model. Here's a **fragment** of the code

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)    
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_1, upper_1)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
   cnt_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
   cnt_area = (cnt_area / (frame_width * frame_height)) * 100
   if cnt_area >= min_contour_area:
     color_detected = True

return color_detected
```

For example:

Light off [image]

Light on [image]

The code is working properly on ideal light conditions. Light in first image should look black, and second image should look yellow. My idea is to apply the same detection algorithm to traffic lights in a variety of light conditions. ***¿Is there a way in which i can correct lightness or add some image processing step to achieve this?***

Comment: You can try detecting an object by circularity. The circularity value is computed as (4*Area*pi)/(Perimeter^2).

Comment: @AlexAlex thanks for answering. The area of the traffic light is already selected so the problem is not detecting where it is located, instead of that, i need to know if it's on or off,   taking into consideration what i've described.

Comment: If you binarize a photo when the traffic light is off, the bright part will have the shape of a cropped circle, because of the shadow at the top.
When the traffic light is on, there is no shadow and the bright part is a circle.

Comment: @AlexAlex I understand now, i'll try that and then i'll let know if it worked. Thanks!